# Swift: Alamofire Documentation

Tags: swift, alamofire

When using Alamofire, I obviously need to make a request at some point. I would like to know what the possible parameters I can pass to request are. I google "Alamofire Request" and sift through the results. Problem is, there are plenty of "usage" examples for Alamofire's request function. But there is no simple function definition that I can find that tells me the possible parameters and their types, which is typically all I need to get something working. Xcode will tell me some of the possible parameters through autocomplete if I type Alamofire followed by a period, but not all of them. Is Alamofire's documentation just bad? (If documentation doesn't even tell you a function's possible parameters, then it's bad documentation.) Or am I looking in the wrong places? Is this typical for Swift documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no documentation like for Swift. But `Alamofire` have documentation in their [GitHub](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/tree/master/Documentation). There is no enough, but if you'll use these docs with documentation from code you'll be fully aware.